# Unable to export RSA Key container file

Tags: asp.net, security, web-config, rsa

I need to encrypt my web.config file on my dev machine (Windows XP SP-3) and export the RSA Key to my QA machine (Windows Server 2003). I used the following command to encrypt my file.

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "appSettings" -app "/VirtualDirectoryName" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

and then i added the following section in my web.config file

```
<configProtectedData>
```

Then i created the RSA container with the name "**SampleKeys**"

Web.Config was encrypted nicely and i was able to use this file on my dev machine. I however had to turn on "Impersonation" and used my windows userName and password.

I need to export my RSA Key to QA server, so that i can use my the encrypted config file.
So i'm trying to export the RSA key and its failing. I don't understand the reason, as i'm following all the steps that are mentioned in the following link;
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2)

When i try to export the RSA container, i get the error saying that the "RSA container was not found." But when i try to create the RSA container again with the same name, i get the error stating "The RSA container already exists". 
[image]

even the following command executed successfully.

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

I however could not execute the following command;

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "SampleKeys" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

I got the same error saying that "RSA container was not found."

I also gave read access to ASPNET user on "C:\Document and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKey" folder.
but nothing worked.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Please help in this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104662/unable-to-encrypt-web-config-file-using-rsa-encryption-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer! You always need to reference the "SampleKeys"-exp once you create a key for exporting.

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "SampleKeys"-exp "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I want to correct... the is wrong. You created a container named "SampleKeys"-exp because the example in the MSDN article is incorrect. The -exp part needs a space between the name and the switch, otherwise it becomes part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to open the command window **as an administrator**. And try again.

Also, in this thread:

http://forums.asp.net/t/960412.aspx/1?RSA+Key+container+was+not+found+ERROR

a default container was created using this command:

aspnet_regiis -pc "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" -exp